# Python + Raspberry Pi - PY-SERIAL ISSUE - why doesn't baud rate matter in my code?

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial, baud-rate

**MY PROBLEM:**

The code below achieves all of my goals for my application except for one problem: my tkinter spinbox sets baud rate and functions correctly (i think). It populates the pyserial baud rate target variable, but no matter what baud rate I specify in the spinbox, the serial communication i receive from my arduino at 9600 continues to be received and displayed fine. (SHOULDN'T IT FAIL IF I SET BAUD TO DIFFERENT RATE?)

I've pared down the code upon request.  Below is the code without any UI, simply printing serial data received to the terminal.  No matter what I set the baud rate to, it continues to work fine.  But the arduino sending serial data is definitely sending at 9600.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#Import Libraries--------------------------
import serial
import Tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
import threading
import sys
import glob
import smtplib
import csv
import tkMessageBox
import datetime

#Setup--------------------------

data = True                     #I'm not sure what this is for

#Thread--------------------------
class SensorThread(threading.Thread):                                   
        def run(self):
                try:
                        i = 0
                        while True:                                     
                                ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 90000)    
                                happenen = ser.readline()               
                                print(happenen)
                                i += 1                                  
                                sleep(1)                                
                except KeyboardInterrupt:                               
                        exit()                                          

#------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
        SensorThread().start()
#------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a [**minimal**, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example? At the moment, it's a code dump, which is not very inviting with all the global calls...

Comment: @OliverW.  Thank you for the tip.  I've reduced it to what I hope is a manageable chunk.  Thanks,

Comment: Now it's incomplete (it definitely won't run properly). I've had a look at the original code. While it has some major design flaws (1: avoid the use of globals. 2: instantiate the serial connection *once* inside your GUI and make it an attribute *of* the GUI. Then launch a thread to monitor the line), did you consider adding `print` statements just before your call to  `ser = serial.Serial(selection, baud)` to see that `baud` is as you expect it from the GUI?

Comment: Well, in my original code, I called print on the baud variable that is feeding the serial.Serial(COM,BAUD).  It printed the correct baud set in the GUI.   However, the code above does run properly insofar as it reads the serial data and prints it to the terminal.  As you can see in this screencapture, i start the script with 90000 baud and it runs, then I change it to 90500 baud, and it runs fine again. it's almost like the baud rate isn't being used and maybe it is auto setting based on what is coming in from the serial port.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-85k87P0BJw&feature=youtu.be